# non-uniqueness to uniqueness of the solution.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

What are the basic things that i have to keep in mind to change the PDE having non unique solution to the PDE have unique solution. 
For example say i have $\Delta u=0 $ for $x\in \Omega$ and $u=1$ in $|x|=1$
 Define $\Omega=x: |x| \ge1$

Here we can clearly see that it has infinite solutions . say $u=a(|x|-1)+1$.

How do i argue to put a condition on the given PDE so that the solution turns out unique. Turning it into dirichlet boundary condition gives uniqueness right ? 
Thanks for help.

Comment: The solution you suggested are not harmonic. Take instead $u=a\ln |x|+1$

Answer (score 3):

The solution of Dirichlet problem for the Laplace operator is unique in a **bounded** domain. You have an unbounded domain (or a set with two components, if in 1 dimension). To achieve uniqueness here, one has to impose a growth bound on the solution, such as o(|x|) in one dimension or $o(\log|x|)$ in two dimensions. If more is known about the domain, the restriction on solution may be less restrictive - see the *Phragmen-Lindelof principle*.

Answer (score 1):

To guarantee uniqueness, additional conditions must generally be specified on the boundary of the region where the solution is defined. Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation#Existence_and_uniqueness).